# CSS files are not working in server using yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I integrated the CSS and JS file in the asset file. On localhost it's working but when I uploaded my project files in cPanel, the UI is breaking.
I can't understand where I'm making the mistake, please help me fix these issues.

Inside the backend folder, I uploaded my AdminLTE-2 CSS and JS files in the web folder. In the asset layout file, I gave the path.

**backend/assets/loginAsset.php**

```
namespace backend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main backend application asset bundle.
 */
class loginAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css',
        'css/AdminLTE.min.css',
        'plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css',
        '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic',
        //'css/site.css',
    ];

    public $js = [
        '//oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js',
        '//oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js',
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        //'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        //'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you check if file is exists in server and you have permission to read file? (I think its file permission issue)

Also make sure your css path inside direction: 
Asset_Management/backend/web/css/AdminLTE.min.css

Comment: localhost also the same folder it's working there but not working and the folder permission also 755

Comment: What about file permission? 

Also is shared hosting or not?

Comment: I find out the issue that is a spelling mistake in server adminlte.min.css but I gave the AdminLTE.min.css

Comment: ues, thats true, since its exsits http://assetman.gunwebhosting.com.au/Asset_Management/backend/web/css/site.css like this :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your code, the issue is usually one of these scenarios:

1. File doesn't exist in **Asset_Management/backend/web/css/AdminLTE.min.css**
2. File does not have a truth permission.
3. Maybe you need to add a truth server configuration to handling **Asset_Management** since by default it must be **backend/web/css/AdminLTE.min.css** nested of **Asset_Management/backend/web/css/AdminLTE.min.css**
4. File Name is wrong, spelling mistake.

Comment: Yes your correct it's spilling mistake inside the server file name is simple letters but in URL I call capital letters. that is the issues

Answer (score 0):

There is a fifth reason why you may not have any css.
At the top of `route\to\your\site\frontend\views\layouts\main.php` or
`route\to\your\site\web\views\layouts\main.php` there must be the following:

```
AppAsset::register($this);
```

Above this you should “use” the class, so either use `frontend\assets\AppAsset;` for advanced yii2 or use `app\assets\AppAsset;` for the yii2 basic. If you don’t register your CSS there is no CSS.